# My DSolve code is running way too slow. How do I make it run faster?

Tags: differential-equations

```
DSolve[y''[x] + (0) y'[
 x] + (a^2 - 900 + (2.3 *10^-8) x - ( 1.5*10^-19) x^2 ) y[
 x] - (900 + (2.3 *10^-8) x - ( 1.5*10^-19) x^2 ) b == 0, y[x], x]
```

I want to solve this differential equation explicitly.

Comment: isn't (0) times anything is zero? I do not understand $(0) y'[....]$ in there. What does it do?

Comment: Hi Nasser. Sorry about that, that term is just 0, I should have just omitted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The scaling of the differential equation seems to be very poor...

Assuming the ode is correct you could substitute `(2.3*10^-8) x->u` and `y[x]->z[u]`

```
dgl /. y -> (z [ (2.3*10^-8) #] &) /. x -> u/2.2999999999999998`*^-8 /. 1. u-> u
(*-b (900 + u - 0.000283554 u^2) + (-900 + a^2 + u - 0.000283554 u^2) z[u] + 5.29*10^-16 (z^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u] == 0 *)
```

The new ode(still not solvable by MMA...) possesses only a very small coefficient in `z''[u]`. If this term can be neglected(perturbation theorie...), you only have to solve the remaining algebraic equation

```
Solve[-b (900 + u - 0.00028355387523629487` u^2) + (-900 + a^2 + u - 
  0.00028355387523629487` u^2) z[u] == 0, z[u]]     
(* {z[u] -> (1. b (900. + u - 0.000283554 u^2))/(-900. + a^2 + u -0.000283554 u^2)} *)
```

Resubstituting gives an approximation `y[x]~z[u=2.3 10^-8 x]`

Comment: Hi Ulrich. What does z[ ] mean? Thanks.

Comment: @user54765: just look at the initial substitution `y[x]->z[u]`. With the last result you get `y[x]=z[u]=z[(2.3*10^-8) x]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want solve symbolicaly it its probably `Mission Impossible`,because Mathematica trying to solve integrals  that has no closed form.

I did not wait when MMA finish calculating.

```
Block[{Integrate}, 
DSolve[y''[x] + (0) y'[x] + (a^2 - 900 + (2.3*10^-8) x - (1.5*10^-19) x^2) y[
x] - (900 + (2.3*10^-8) x - (1.5*10^-19) x^2) b == 0, y[x], 
x] /. {Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate]}] // Simplify

(* huge expression with ParabolicCylinderD integrals *)
```

Simplified code if $y'(x)\neq 0$:

```
Block[{Integrate}, 
DSolve[y''[x] + y'[x] + (a^2 - 900 + (A) x - (B) x^2) y[
x] - (900 + (A) x - (B) x^2) b == 0, y[x], 
x] /. {Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate]}] // Simplify
(* huge expression with HermiteH and Hypergeometric1F1 integrals *)
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks Mariusz.